# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [German Language Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to explain the ending -en in "dem alten Hafenviertel" if we know it's in dative?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/how-to-explain-the-ending-en-in-dem-alten-hafenviertel-if-we-know-its-in-dat)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do you structure a German sentence to represent the English construct "at [action]"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/how-do-you-structure-a-german-sentence-to-represent-the-english-construct-at-a)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Hoch und tief mit Jahreszeiten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10339/hoch-und-tief-mit-jahreszeiten)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Tight and Narrow = Eng und Schmal?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10607/tight-and-narrow-eng-und-schmal)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I know which declension pattern a noun belongs to in the Langenscheidt pocket dictionary?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10577/how-do-i-know-which-declension-pattern-a-noun-belongs-to-in-the-langenscheidt-po)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Wie sagt man "Hug bug" auf Deutsch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10534/wie-sagt-man-hug-bug-auf-deutsch)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What's the difference between "bereiten" and "vorbereiten"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10593/whats-the-difference-between-bereiten-and-vorbereiten)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Accurate words to communicate the concept of "dating"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10612/accurate-words-to-communicate-the-concept-of-dating)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Difference between "Wechselwirkungen" and "Interaktion" in the context of social interactions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/difference-between-wechselwirkungen-and-interaktion-in-the-context-of-social)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "worden" und "geworden"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10649/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-worden-und-geworden)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---